# Flutter - ListView renders only 1 child from a list

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, listview

I have a for loop in a FutureBuilder:

```
       for (var doc in exercises) {
        bool isRowsGeneratedForPreviousExercises = false;
        dataRowsForCompletedExercises = [];
        var setList = [];
        Map<String, dynamic> exercise;
        var exerciseName = '';
        exercise = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        setList = exercise['sets'];
        exerciseName = exercise['name'];
        if (!(doc.id == exerciseId)) {
          for (var set in setList) {
            var weight = '';
            var reps = '';
            var isToFailure = false;
            weight = set['weight'].toString();
            reps = set['reps'].toString();
            isToFailure = set['isToFailure'];
            if (isRowsGeneratedForPreviousExercises == false) {
              _generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises(
                weight,
                reps,
                isToFailure,
              );
              isRowsGeneratedForPreviousExercises = true;
            }
          }
        }
        completedExercisesWidgetsList.add(
            _completedExercisesDataTableWidget(exerciseName)

        print('LIST LENGTH = ' +
            completedExercisesWidgetsList.length.toString());

     }//for loop ends

       return ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: completedExercisesWidgetsList,
      );
    }
```

The length of completedExercisesWidgetsList is 6 at the end of the loop; however only 1 child is rendered. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will need to see more information about the parent of ListView.

Two things you need to look into,

- `scrollDirection` of the list view
- `height` of the parent widget

With the above code, try to increase the `height` parent widget. Look higher up the widgets to see if you have a `SizedBox` or `Container` with a `height` property.

Alternatively you can change the `scrollDirection` of the `ListView` to `Axis.horizontal` and you will see most of the widget and the list will scroll horizontally.